Give a multiline element the length of its longest line
I have a paragraph with text that wraps. How can I make the paragraph take the width of its longest line that fits inside inside its parent/ inside the grid cell containing this paragraph?
Basically, for the text below, I want the paragraph (orange background box) width be the same as the length of the longest pink line:

Which line is the longest depends on how much text fits/ how it rearranges as the paragraph's parent/ the grid cell containing it changes size:


Making the parent a grid and setting place-self: center (which is the whole point of limiting its width too, I want it to be the length of the longest line so that I can middle align it) on the paragraph doesn't work - the paragraph occupies the width of its entire grid cell, it's not limited to the length of its longest line.

Can you add refrence tempalte that you have tried.

You can achieve this by writing a simple script. In this code, getBoundingClientRect().width retrieves the width of the selected element ("#textContent") using the getBoundingClientRect() method and sets it to width of the ("#paragraph") element.


function removeWidth() {
  document.querySelector("#paragraph").style.width = document.querySelector("#textContent").getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
}
removeWidth();
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
p {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px
}
<p id="paragraph"><span id="textContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus cupiditate commodi nam porro modi qui atque nesciunt architecto magnam quis optio corrupti eligendi repudiandae, delectus voluptatibus non voluptatum aliquid natus!</span></p>



